# How are fonts rendered in Flutter or how do I avoid vertical spacing?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, text-widget

I have two simple `Text`-Widgets in a `Row` that have different font sizes. I use `CrossAxisAlignment.start` to vertically place them at the beginning of the vertical axis. Unfortunately, the two text chunks are not correctly aligned. When I use `Flutter: Inspect Widget` in VSCode, I can see that both `Text`-Widgets have some vertical spacing to the top of the row, which increases with font size. This reminds me of the `line-height` attribute in **CSS**, but I have not found an equivalent in Flutter.

Is there any way to render a `Text`-Widget's content without this spacing?

To reproduce this behavior, use the following `Row` inside the Flutter Create demo App:

```dart
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('First', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),),
    Text('Second', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Have you tried the TextStyle "height" property? default is 1

Comment: @TizianoMunegato , thanks for the response. I was able to use the `height` property and with double values like `0.8` or `0.9` I have been able to accomplish what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: @NielsVocke did you find other solution instead of using the height property with these random values like `0.8` or `0.9`?

Answer (score 0):

1.0 is a percentage of the font-size I think. Maybe 18%?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html